# April Fools 2013

Tags: discussion

As many of you may (or may not) know, shortly before April Fools' day, we decided that fruit was fantastic and that we should spend the day asking as many fruit-related questions as possible, with loosened bounds on what was, and was not, allowed.

The result is 24 questions (rivaling, at the time, [one-piece](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-piece) and [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production)) about various fruits stemming from our commitment to being festive around the holidays. Some were not constructive and have been deleted, others are perfectly valid, and some even have answers!

The links have been archived here for onlookers and other such interested parties.

- [What causes people who come in contact with the “Time Fruit” to change?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3131/274)
- [Does Doraemon have any gadgets which involve fruits in the anime?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3132/274)
- [What kinds of Fruits are in the Basket?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3133/274)
- [What happens if a Devil Fruit is destroyed?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3134/274)
- [Why is Toradora's ED about oranges?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3135/274)
- [Where did the strawberry pantsu trope originate?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3136/274)
- [What is the meaning behind the ongoing gag with Spain and bananas?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3137/274)
- [Why does Nana have to eat bananas with their skins on as a condition to use her powers?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3138/274)
- [Is the Fruit of Grisaia an actual fruit?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3139/274)
- [Where does Kyoko get those delicious looking apples?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3140/274)
- [What anime are all of these fruits from?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3141/274)
- [When did people start calling “manga” as “mangos”?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3144/274)
- [What are the different versions of Fruits Candy?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3147/274)
- [Why were the 765 idols dressed as fruits?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3152/274)
- [Are the Tuffles actually fruits?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3153/274)
- [What is the meaning of the title “Bad Apple”, and which characters appear?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3162/274)
- [Are the Sailor Moon colors based on types of fruit?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3171/274)
- [What is the significance behind the apples and boxes?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3173/274)
- [Why does Trisha Elric have tomatoes?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3182/274)
- [From what anime is this character who is holding an apple?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3183/274)
- [Are the honey-pickled apples from Spice and Wolf historically accurate?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3186/274)
- [Why is Tangelo Island named as such?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3187/274)
- [Does each Sohmas' appearance correlate to a fruit?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3194/274)
- [Why does Ryuk love apples?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3195/274)

(*Note: As some of these are deleted, you need the [access to moderator tools](https://anime.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege to see them.*)

Comment: shouldn't this be locked or closed or something, it's not really a question and doesn't really merit any answers.

Comment: @iKlsR Not all questions on meta are "questions". Meta is mostly an information and discussion site about the main site, so its rules differ slightly. It is a bit misleading that the software still labels them as such, but [not all posts on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/192960) have answers.