# What we'd like to do about those gosh darn "identification requests" questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, identification-questions

> **This discussion is now closed.**
>   [Here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2812/identification-request-cleanup-phase-1-deprecation)'s phase 1 of what we've decided to do about identification-requests (deprecating).
>   [Here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2824/identification-request-cleanup-phase-2-blacklisting)'s phase 2 (blacklisting).
>   [Here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3839/49)'s phase 3 (delete and lock).

**TL;DR for those who want to find alternative resources for ID request: [What identification requests are acceptable here? Otherwise, where else can I possibly get helped with it?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4189/2516)**

---

The topic of id-request is a very subjective one. I believe that it's difficult to provide an objective data for analysis. Afterall [correlation does not imply causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation).

Id-requests are something we struggled with dealing with since they first came up on our site. Objectively on paper, they can make decent questions. But in practice, this is far from true. Some common complaints about these types of question are that:

- **They are too localized and oftentimes vaguely worded**, and typically unhelpful to other users. Someone trying to remember the same thing as you might recall certain details more vividly than others, this oftentimes results in different descriptions of the same thing.

  There's no easy way to resolve this. Answering identification question is not unlike giving directions: if you don't give someone good directions they'll have a hard time finding what they are looking for.

  Take a look at this map, made by a directionally-challenged character from a popular manga:

  [image: Ryouga is directionally challenged]

  [image: Really challenged]

  Would you find what you're looking for or where you need to go? The place you're looking for based off of these directions? Probably not. However more often than not we get users the ask question that feel like these maps, despite our attempts to help them include better details with [our guidelines](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/891/what-criteria-should-we-use-for-qcing-for-all-identification-request-questions/892#892).
- **Users make little effort, but expect the world in return.** We've seen a lot of these types of id request questions. Most of them are in the form of image-only id requests, which got out of hand really quick, mostly because the ones asking the question almost never tried doing a reverse image search themselves and expect us to do it and tell them. We're not here to be someone's personal search engine/concierge service, we're here to ask and answer questions about the world and culture of anime and manga. *Filling our site with these questions can be as bad as watching filler episodes of a long-running anime.* It gets us nowhere.

  [Since then we've disallowed media-only (only a link to an image, audio, video) identification questions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2725/policy-review-image-only-id-requests/2726#2726), but we've made some provisions to allow users to ask questions about identifying *specific* [merchandise](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merchandise), [cosplay](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosplay), and the rare but occasional [itasha](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/itasha), using actual pictures that you've seen or taken yourself.

  As of this post, the [help center](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) topic for what's on-topic and our [tour page](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tour) have been updated to note that users should follow these guidelines when asking identification request questions, including our updated stance on media-only identification requests.
- **Rarely do users that ask id-requests stick around or bother to come back.** Statistically speaking the [retention numbers](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2467/can-we-get-some-more-definitive-numbers-on-identification-request-stats) on id-request askers are low. Not only that, but a fair number of them are asked by unregistered users, whose  accounts are cookie-based and volatile, meaning that once they lose their session cookie, they have no way of logging back to this account (without registering that account). This results in many id request questions being essentially abandoned.

While we care about making more of an effort to downvote and close these questions, the fact that these post continue to pop up and with the same issues, is a bit of a cause for concern.

I, for one, do not like to see the current trend of where identification questions are going and would like to start deprecating them. We've made many efforts and guides to help users write better identification questions, but as time goes by, reminding them of such gets pretty tedious. Our previous stance was to downvote and close these questions based on our guidelines. That's all fine and done, but it requires users to actively pay attention to these questions as they come up via the review queue or on the main page. Instead of devoting our time to dealing with these questions, I'd like to see our community's efforts direct to community development between users. We've done gift exchanges, viewing sessions, and even a multi-discipline project like game development: I'd like to see us nurture this spirit more. Therefore, I believe it's in the community's best interest to deprecate and eventually remove identification questions in their entirety from our site.

I do understand that there is opposition to removing the questions completely, which is why I'd like to give them one last chance to not only be heard but also defend their position on this matter and what they believe would help improve the situation of dealing with the influx of low quality and abandoned id-requests. Maybe we've overlooked something, maybe we could have done something better, or maybe we went about things in the wrong manner.

You may discuss or scrutinize the plans as much as you'd like here on meta or in [our main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-). Regardless of how much or how little reputation you have in this community, your proposal will be heard equally, as long as there is consensus on it within the community. However, **note that this is likely to be the final time to voice your opinions**. I would like us to finally reach a decisive conclusion on this matter once and for all.

You have until **May 8th** to make your case (for, against, other) and leave any comments.

However, while such question are off-topic on our site, they will still be welcome [in our main chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-) for users with with at least [20 rep](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) (globally on StackExchange).

Comment: This is the part where I get to say I TOLD YOU SO.

Comment: @senshin Yes, you did. You were right.

Comment: Why not just do like Arqade and require a screenshot, video, or audio clip?

Comment: So... the end result is now that all these questions just end up on scifi.SE, which is probably less-better-equipped to answer them. Personally I would've been much happier to see these type of questions retained and allowed here, but only allowed to remain open if they were of high quality, i.e. had sufficient detail to be answered.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am against keeping identification question on the site and I believe that there are quite a few users within the community that feel that same way on this matter. I would like to propose the following plan for deprecating and getting rid of them:

1. Start closing all *NEW* [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) questions with a modification to the existing off-topic close reason to remind users that all identification questions are off-topic. **All users are encouraged to vote to close them as they pop up.**
2. After <s>30</s> **15 days**, blacklist the [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) and associated tag synonyms, close *ALL* remaining [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) questions, and apply a [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) to them. This will most likely be done via a [feature-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) to the CMs.
3. After <s>60</s> **30 days**, delete all [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) questions with a score of <s>3 or less</s> less than 4, without at least one answer with a score of 3 or more. The ones that remain will serve as a reminder to other (new) users that while we have allowed these question in the past, these question are no longer on-topic on our site. These questions will remain and be [untagged](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) and locked permanently. Future questions should not only be locked, but also deleted.

   Doing so will is meant to preserve some of the better identification request questions for purposes of keeping historical artefacts. The three-step process is meant to be less abrupt and ease everyone into the removal of the [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) tag and questions tagged with it.

Removing the tag will most definitely have a rather significant impact on our question and answer count. This is why, in return, I would like to us to start organizing more community events to talk about, recommend, and watch anime in a monthly basis (or weekly, if the initiative gains enough traction).

Some examples would be short weekly collaborative watch sessions for on-going seasonal anime (two sessions, each one for people in different time zones), and a monthly binge session of an entire complete series or set of movies following a theme (there will be 2 time slots to accommodate different time zones as well).

There is also the possibility of hosting themed community events involving asking question on certain tags: we've done similar things in the past, both when with [seasonal tags](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags-by-season?sort=newest&pageSize=50) and [themed tags](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/510/april-fools-2013).

I'll give you guys until the **end of the next month (May 8th)** to mull over this, before implementing anything.

[This](http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/480246/identification-questions-that-wouldnt-be-deleted-q4-a3?MaxQuestionScoreToDelete=3&MinAnswerScoreToKeep=3) is a modified version of @Makoto's data query that shows the question that will be kept.

However, while such question are off-topic on our site, they are still welcome [in our main chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-) for users with with at least [20 rep](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) (globally on StackExchange).

Comment: if we are keeping some of the good id requests then i can't see how we can remove the tag at all

Comment: @Memor-X We can remove the tag from the questions and lock them with a historical lock.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha i thought a tag can only be removed if it's not in use

Comment: @Memor-X since the tag would be blacklisted similar to the anime tag, you would not be able to add the tag to a question

Comment: I fear you're being *far* too optimistic about the quality of these questions, and even more conservative with the bounds you specify.  [I've created an SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/476493/identification-questions-with-a-minimum-question-score-and-answer-score?MinQuestionScore=10&MinAnswerScore=5) to play around with min question score and min answer score.  You can see if there's anything that's exemplary in there, but I'm not as confident.

Comment: Also, I see no reason why the blacklist couldn't be instantaneous outside of technical limitations, which would imply that we need more hamsters for the server farm... ;)

Comment: [Here's the same query](http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/476493/identification-questions-with-a-minimum-question-score-and-answer-score?MinQuestionScore=10&MinAnswerScore=5) revamped to indicate if a question has been closed.  If you want to *exclude* those kinds of questions, it's not too tough from here.

Comment: Is step (2) going to "catch" questions like [this one](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/12989/2604), which presumably might still be acceptable under the new policy?

Comment: @Maroon It should be possible to catch questions like that fairly easy by looking for [identification-request] posts that are also tagged with a series or movie. Also your SEDE query doesn't seem to match the criteria given in this post for an id-request to not be deleted. As I read it, if question has a score of 4 or more, OR if a question has an answer with a score of 4 or more it's not deleted. Here's an updated query: http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/476523/identification-questions-that-wouldnt-be-deleted

Comment: @Maroon that one should have never been tagged with id-req. Id-reqs should never have a series tag.

Comment: Curious, would asking to id the name of a doujin that belongs to a series based off a page or id-ing music from within a series become off-topic?

Comment: @Memor-X Music identification is series specific, so it's not an id-req. Questions about doujinshi should be acceptable. However identifying a doujinshi of a specific series is an id-req and should not include a series tag as there really is no direct connection. However if you wish would like to ask about finding a doujinshi a specific author did on a specific series, then you can use the author name and the series name as tags. This makes identifying the title more specific and answerable, as opposed to grasping for straws in the dark like we currently do for id-reqs.

Comment: @RossRidge:  That was actually my query, and I do feel like it's an AND - we're trying to catch questions with a score greater than 3 and at least one answer with a score greater than 3.  That actually shows what's going to be *kept*.  If you want the inverse, flip the inequalities.

Comment: @Makoto Sorry, about the misattribution. That's not what "questions with a score of 3 or less without at least one answer with a score of 3 or more"  means. It means a question must have score of 3 or less AND be without at least one answer with a score of 3 or more" in order to be deleted. If you reverse it you get "a question must have a score of 4 or more OR have (be not without) at least one question with a score of 3 or more" in order to be kept.

Comment: When will this closure come into effect? We will need a new closure reason

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko well it hasn't been a week since this meta was even posted. i know all out VTC Trigger Fingers are twitching with anticipation we need to give the subject a bit of time so people can have their say

Comment: @Memor-X indeed - I should have been clearer, I just would like some disambiguity between the "Now" now and the "Now" in the future, so that people aren't confused.

Comment: ++++++1, go forward, so that i can also stole the idea for movies.se and give a successful example of implemented site.

Comment: You said in the question that we have until May 8 to make our case, but you'll start implementing things after May 1? Suggestions: 1) before implementing anything, it would be courteous to the community to provide in the post a SQL query (probably not the one updated by Ross Ridge) that correctly identifies the questions that would be removed according to the criteria. 2) divide the post removals into phases, so for example you'll delete questions with negative scores with no upvoted answers by date XXX, then you'll delete questions with < 1 score with no answers > 3 scores by date YYY.

Comment: I have a slight objection to the criteria. I think if an answer gets >= 3 (or 5) votes on questions with < 3 && >= -1 votes, they should be considered before deleting them right away. 3 is the mark for well-received (or good) posts on SE. Also, is there any way to separate the upvotes from the downvotes? IMO, a post with 3 upvotes and 3 downvotes is different from a post with 0 upvotes and 0 downvotes, although both balance out to be 0 net score. By design, an upvote assigns more reputation than a downvote takes away, so 3/3 is not equivalent to 0/0.

Comment: @Gao May 1st is a typo on my part. May 8th is the drop dead date. Using [this modified query](http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/480246/identification-questions-that-wouldnt-be-deleted-q4-a3?MaxQuestionScoreToDelete=3&MinAnswerScoreToKeep=3) you can see the questions that will be kept as of this post there are 413, which is still a lot.  There are currently about 2,194 id-req questions. I believe that shifting through them is them and removing it bit by bit has no actual benefit. Afterall someone has to spend time sift through these questions and schedule the tasks.

Comment: @Gao Just because 3 pp upvote a question, while 3 ppl downvote it doesn't make it a "good" question. It makes the question controversial. We want to leave some of the better examples of id-req as an example of how they should be asked or answered, but at the same time, we don't want too many of them to be left over as they will be tagged as "untagged."

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ Thanks for the explanation and prompt edit. The current criteria seems be the best option for now, even though I believe many on that list aren't worth keeping and some not on that list are.

Answer (score 9):

Id requests suck, I've been convinced for quite a while that we should get rid of them, and I agree with ʞɹɐzǝɹ's plan to do so.

While there are many reasons they suck, and many reasons to get rid of them, I want to focus on one in particular--it takes way too much time and energy to police them.

On a typical day, I visit the site four or five times. Each of those times, there's usually at least one new id request to look at (I view the site from the "All questions" tab, ordered from newest to oldest). It's usually written as one long sentence all in a single paragraph in shoddy English, with awful punctuation and incomprehensible word use. Sometimes this is because the asker is a non-native speaker of English, but sometimes the asker is a native speaker of English who is just too lazy or ignorant to put any effort into decent writing. I have no way to tell, so I have to go in and make paragraphs and use commas and fix typos to make it minimally presentable. I've also started cutting out all the useless fluff that people add to id requests—"Thanks in advance", "When I was young I saw this show I really liked", "Please excuse my poor English", "I'm going crazy trying to find this", "It was really cute", "It had great art", "I met my spouse because of this manga", etc.

There's also been a rash of users recently who don't understand how tags work for some reason, so they just toss a bunch of random tags on their question instead of tagging it [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request). [naruto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto), [bleach](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bleach), [pokemon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon), [dragon-ball](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball) are all common but I just voted to close a question which had been wrongly tagged [satisfaction-guaranteed](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satisfaction-guaranteed). So those have to be changed. (Since so many of our questions are id requests, it boggles my mind that they didn't see another question tagged [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) and figure out how they were supposed to do it. But id questioners do keep finding new, inventive ways to suck.)

Then the question is usually horribly vague, so I leave a comment asking the OP to add more information, like when they saw it, where they saw it, what exact year it was, etc. Typically I also downvote, and sometimes vote to close. Since I like to retract downvotes and close votes if it's justified, I come back later to check on it and see if the OP has done anything to improve the question. Very rarely is that the case. Usually the OP has posted some kind of whiny comment asking why everyone is complaining when that's really all they remember. Sometimes I try to explain to them why their question is bad, but it's usually a waste of time.

This process becomes draining, tedious, and frustrating after a while. I imagine it's also frustrating for the question asker. Also, the time I spend doing this is time I'm on the site, not asking or answering questions--in other words, not actually building up the site, but rather just trying to stop it collapsing under the weight of bad questions. Not making a better site, just trying to prevent it becoming a worse site.

I know it's not just me. I can see other users doing the same thing—users who once contributed great questions and answers, some of the best on the site, now spend all their time on the site sifting through garbage on the off chance of finding, not a diamond, but maybe an AA battery that isn't quite dead yet, or a jar that could make a good container for nuts and bolts and screws. I can see these users making the same edits, leaving the same comments asking for more information, voting to close, arguing with whiny questioners who expect service two hours ago, dammit, and an apology from the manager for the waiter's rudeness.

It's just not worth all this trouble. Whatever value id requests add to the site—and, as we've discussed before, many of us believe they don't add much—that value is not worth all the time it takes to police them according to the strict, baroque guidelines we've set for them. Instead, we could have users out there writing better questions, or answering better questions. If we ban them, they'll keep showing up, and we'll still have to vote to close them, but just automatically casting a vote to close isn't nearly as draining, tedious, and frustrating as that entire process of trying to goad an unwilling OP into writing a decent question.

Comment: If it's taking too much time to police them, maybe we're doing it wrong. Just [downvote anything that looks remotely horrendous and move on, after having also casted a close vote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252740). What I propose we do instead is refine the close reasons and classify/clarify them better so that we don't have to explain in the comment everytime why the questions are being closed. If the id-asker still complains, they aren't welcome anyway, since they can't read.

Comment: @Gao that's what we do on Stack Overflow. I don't want us to moderate our content like we do on Stack Overflow. We're not nearly at that scale to make it justified.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha But if we remove ids, aren't we also moderating content, a priori? We would piss people off either way.

Comment: There's a big difference between saying "We, as a community, don't like those, and don't allow them anymore", and "We like them, but we'll downvote everything and never come back to them, to check for improvements"

Comment: If the OP improves (hopefully) the post, it will enter the review queue anyway, so we will check them (hopefully). Just an observation: Arqade allows only ids with concrete screenshot. We disallow ids with concrete screenshot/images (except merchandise) and allow text-only ids. Interesting?

Comment: @Gao That's basically what we've been doing: "clarifying" our guidelines (i.e. making them more and more byzantine, with more and more exceptions, subheadings, and articles) and writing new meta posts every so often, stating the same guidelines in different ways, in the hopes that new users will see it. But people keep asking the same kind of questions and coming back with the defense "But that's all I remember!". I suspect many of them *do* read the guidelines, but because the guidelines are so complex and so subjective, they can't really tell if their question is okay, so they just post.

Answer (score 6):

Originally I would be for keeping [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) on-topic on the grounds that it can be a good starting point for new users.

**HOWEVER!**

I have now changed my stance. I am in agreement with [making them off-topic and the removal of low scoring questions.](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2806/1587)

My original view was that making an id-request question wasn't hard, and that new users would be able to post good quality questions. However this has not been the case, and the community has had to

- [Show how to do reverse images searches](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/where-is-this-picture-from-how-do-i-use-reverse-image-search-to-find-the-source)
- [Establish minimum guidelines](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/891/what-criteria-should-we-use-for-qcing-for-all-identification-request-questions/892#892)
- Remind users about these:

  - [When using the tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdKqJ.png)
  - [In the tag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info)
  - [In the Tour](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tour)
  - [In the the help center](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

in an attempt to try and improve the quality, but it appears that new users — and sometimes normal users who never used the tag before — seem to ignore all of these.

However, we can't put all the blame on questions. Stack Exchange is a Question *and Answer* Site. Making a lot of high quality questions is one thing, but we also want high quality answers too.

Like questions, I thought that new users could easily answer an id-request and get some rep — since 1 upvote = 10 rep, and accept = 15 rep, compared to questions which were 1 upvote = 5 rep. And writing a good answer to an id-request isn't hard: you name a title you believe that matches, give a description of the title then list how the title matches and possibly what parts may have been misremembered.

However, too many times, when I see an answer to an id-request by a new user, they are just one-liners, sometimes with a link, sometimes an illegal site and sometimes with padding crap like:

> it's Sakamoto desu ga!!!!!!!!!......................need 150 characters<sup>1</sup>

and even when the community posts a comment notifying them of this, it usually falls on deaf ears and another user has to use their time to edit the answer to include even a description of the mentioned title.

While other users editing answer isn't new, it's normally formatting, re-organizing text to flow better and removing banter. But for id-requests, users are more than often editing answers to add in new information (such as the case with [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/31672/revisions)). Aside from the fact that the editing user is giving up time for another user who clearly doesn't want to put any effort into their *own* post, a third-party adding in more info into an answer is traditionally an edit rejection on the ground of conflicting with the author's intent (with the exception to quoting content from links).

---

Another thing is that id-requests are also the only tag which one can't ask and answer at the same time. Sometimes when a user discovers something interesting they post a good question and answer it, sharing their knowledge with the community.

However with id-requests you can't do that. As per what Krazer has said in the question and in [JNat's comment](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/what-wed-like-to-do-about-those-gosh-darn-identification-requests-questions?cb=1#comment6566_2808), how one person might recall a title could be very different from how anyone else might do it. Self-answering an id-request doesn't really add any valuable knowledge when compared to [this self answered question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/23753/1587).

Even when the user doesn't abandon the question, when they ended up finding the titles they wanted identified they end up self-answering with a one-liner, which is one of the problems.

---

<sup>1: can't remember if it was 150 characters or not, but you get the idea</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I'm on the fence about this but because no one has posted a contrary opinion yet, I'll offer this up. I'm uncertain about this because as I see it, there's one good reason why identification questions should be a banned, and few admittedly not as good reasons why they should be allowed. Given the balance between the two, I'm of the opinion we should err on the side of caution and so continue to allow identification requests.

#### One good reason to get rid of them

Identification requests have one fundamental problem, and it's a pretty damning one. It unlikely that when answered they'll be all that helpful to anyone other than person asking the question. That's not what these Stack Exchange sites are supposed to be about. If questions only helped the asker then it wouldn't be worth the expense of running a site like this. The value in these sites comes from the fact that one question can end up helping a lot of people.

Now, I'm not saying questions should judged based on how many people they might help. There is a good reason why the [old "too localized" close reason was removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185102/responding-to-your-too-localized-concerns), there just isn't a good way to set objective criteria for judging whether individual posts could help "enough" people. This is different though, this is an entire class of questions that don't seem to add much value to the site. That's a reasonable justification for not allowing them.

#### A few reasons to keep them

The one saving grace here is that while identification requests are unlikely to be helpful to someone else trying to identify something, they still are of some value to people browsing the site. I read them to see if they mention anything interesting, some show that I never heard of and may like. It's not big thing but they do seem to gather views at rate similar to other kinds of posts, so they must have some value beyond helping the person asking the question.

What I think is the most compelling reason to keep them is that we seem to do a relatively good job of answering them. There doesn't seem to be another place that does a better job. It's not a question of the site lacking the expertise. There's also nothing that makes these questions fundamentally unanswerable or outside the scope of the site. This isn't a case where these questions don't fit the Q/A format. They aren't ones we can say are better suited to a more traditional discussion forum.

While this doesn't matter much as it used to, getting rid of identification requests would take a big chuck out of the activity on this site. The good thing is that since this site is no longer in beta, there's no fear of closure as a result (plus they changed graduation criteria so it's no longer activity based anyways). Still, it's not obvious this would help improve the overall health of the site. It's easy to say that people asking identification requests almost never post again and aren't contributing to the site, so banning them won't hurt, but that is actually hard to measure. While it's true not many accounts post again, it's hard to say how many people are posting using new accounts, having forgotten or lost the old one.

The lowered activity can have snowball affect as well. People who see a less active site are not as likely to become active. If you're someone like me, who isn't interested in shounen fighting anime, then this site effectively becomes a lot less active. I've probably read more identification questions here than not. Active users may end up becoming less active.

So I think there's actually some risk to banning these questions. There's lots of hard to predict ways their absence could negatively affect activity, like less word of mouth, lower search rankings, and the site not showing up in the "Hot Network Questions" list as much (though this site's id requests don't seem to show up there as much as other sites).

Finally, another reason to keep them is the fact that things have actually gotten better. The site now has better criteria for closing bad identification questions. The growth in these questions has plateaued, and no longer [threaten to take over the site](http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/261651/the-identification-requests-are-taking-over-cumulative?TagName=identification-request#graph). So, just when they've gotten under control they should now be eliminated completely?

Comment: +1 for raising the possible snowball effect and not knowing if id askers return and registered for new account. As to how helpful ids are, I liken them to questions on code review. Unless you're reviewing code for a popular project, they aren't likely to help many people, yet code review exists as an SE subnetwork.

Comment: [It actually *is* easy to say that users that post identification requests don't contribute to the site.](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/2468/102)  The activity from users asking identification requests here is sporadic and not long lasting, and if we're basing our participation on one of those statistics alone, then we're in a pretty bad spot.

Comment: @Makoto As I said it's easy to get numbers based on accounts. Finding numbers based on actual people is harder.

Comment: I like the point that these questions can be interesting to read, but lately, I frankly haven't really enjoyed reading the questions that have popped up, so this doesn't really help me enjoy the site more (even though as of right now, I'm not interested in most of the anime that has been asked about on the front page).

Comment: "There doesn't seem to be another place that does a better job." - my house could, in principle, serve as a venue for persons looking for a place to fling excrement at the walls, and I'm sure I cpuld outfit my house to serve that purpose quite well. And yet I somehow manage to resist the urge to invite excrement-flingers to my home.

Comment: @senshin You've taken that out of context, it's not just this place does a better job, it's also that we do a good job of it, and the questions fit the scope and format of the site. It's like a zoo getting rid of it's monkeys because they behave like monkeys.

Comment: I've also been saying recently that we do a good job of answering id requests and that there's nowhere better. No, a "good" job doesn't even begin to cover it--we do a heroic job of answering them, and our format and skill vastly surpasses any other venue. But I've also supported banning them for a fairly long time, because they just suck. They don't have to suck as much as they do--SF&F's story ident questions actually aren't that bad--but somehow the crowd we attract by having them is just full of lazy, entitled, illiterate people who are too lazy to correct "mocha" to "mecha".

Comment: I think your metaphor--"a zoo getting rid of monkeys because they behave like monkeys"--is misplaced. The crappiness of id requests is a combination of immature people in our community and the qualities of the question type that make it attractive to those people. It's more like we have these monkeys (id requests) that behave like monkeys, and for that reason we need zoo visitors not to egg them on. Then a bunch of kids come in and start yelling and screaming and hooting and carrying on and making faces at the monkeys. We can do two things: kick out the kids, or get rid of the monkeys.

Comment: Except that in our case we can't kick out the kids, because more kids who behave the same way keep coming in. We can't stop them coming in. We can't keep kicking them out, because our zoo will get a bad reputation and people will stop coming. Our clientele is just not mature enough to have monkeys around. While it would really be nice if we could change our clientele and make them mature enough to handle monkeys, like the clientele over at that Science Fiction and Fantasy Zoo, it's not realistic. So we have to get rid of the monkeys, and replace them with some donkeys or something.

Comment: @Evilloli Well, let me put it another way. You would expect a zoo to have monkeys. You would expect a Anime & Manga Q&A site to be able to identify an anime or manga. Banning id-request isn't going to change that expectation, not if the people who ask these questions only ever post one question and never return. They'll never get the chance to learn differently. So these posts won't stop, they'll just be all closed now. Kids will still come to the zoo expecting to see monkeys. Maybe they'll spread the word that zoo doesn't have monkeys anymore, more likely they'll tell everyone that zoo sucks.

Comment: @Evilloli On the other hand, what makes this different from a monkey-less zoo is that while getting rid of monkeys makes room for something else, that's not the case here. This site is one of the smallest in the Stack Exchange network, there's already room for it to get a 1000 times bigger. Better questions won't be sucked into fill the vacuum left by the loss of the id-requests. This site will simply just shrink. The monkeys won't be replaced with donkeys, the monkey habitat will simply be left empty. Donkeys won't just wander in on their own.

Comment: The answer I just posted presents my thoughts on your first comment. In terms of the zoo metaphor: it takes a lot less energy to stop monkey-seeking kids at the gates and tell them "No monkeys, take a hike" than it does to let them in, let them start acting out, round them all up, and kick them out, then repeat the process several times a day every day.

Comment: ʞɹɐzǝɹ presented some ideas to encourage more questions to fill in the gap. Yes, we might shrink. I'm not worried about it. If it's a choice between quality or quantity, I choose the former. Since we're not a beta anymore, it's unlikely that SE will shut us down, and several on the SE staff have an aversion to id requests anyway, so if anything they'll be happy that we've gotten rid of them.

Comment: @Evilloli Those ideas are orthogonal to banning id-requests. If they can actually get better questions they can get better questions regardless of whether id-requests are allowed. Your right that banning them will make it easier to police them. Though personally it doesn't seem too bad to me, not compared to what I see on Stack Overflow. However I don't really do any policing here, SO keeps me busy enough with that, so I'm not really in a position to judge.

Comment: Re: the fact that ID requests fit the site, and that we answer them well. Low-effort "translation" ("what does this Chinese text mean") or reference ("how do I pronounce this word") questions are usually not allowed on language SE's, even though top users tend to be pretty good at answering those.

Comment: I don't do much moderation on Stack Overflow, but I too see a ton of really awful, vague, poorly written questions. What's shocking is that, proportional to our size, I see just as many here. None of the other smaller sites I frequent has that many bad questions. I argued in my answer that moderating all these bad questions takes away time that people might be using to ask and answer good questions, so banning id requests is *not* orthogonal to getting more good questions, because policing them takes away the time of potential good question writers.

Comment: Why is the fact that we seem to be the place that identifies anime better of any importance here? We can still keep doing that in chat, and don't need to fill our front page with crap just because we seem to be the best community in the 'net doing it. Is it worth filling our site with low-quality questions, prone to be abandoned by the hit-and-run users who ask them, just because we appear to be able to do it better than anyone else? What benefit to they bring to the table? Do they help other users? Is anyone going to remember the same anime in the same way and find it through that...

Comment: (cont'd) same question? Are the users even sticking around to help us grow and to help others after they get their answer? Do they even care if we downvote and close their questions, and come back to edit and improve them? These put a great toll on our community, as part of it spends time and effort trying to help a single person, and not the community — in that sense, id-requests do _not_ fit well into our format: they may fit well into the Q&A format, but not into the SE philosphy.

Comment: We're better off motivating users to positively contribute to our community, so they earn enough rep to go to chat and ask about the anime they're looking for there — win-win situation: we can _still_ be the top place in the 'net to get your anime identified, and we rid our front page of this disease _while_ helping our community grow.

Comment: @JNat Again, it's not just that one factor. It's the fact the questions are within the scope of "Anime and Manga", it's the fact that the questions fit the Stack Exchange Q/A format and it's the fact that we have a community of experts that are good at answering the questions. Normally when a whole class of questions are banned on a SE site one or more of these factors isn't true. When this happens despite all of them being true there should be a very good reason. I argue that in this case, while there is one good reason for getting rid of them anyways it's not quite sufficient.

Comment: @JNat Also, I don't think chat is going to be a substitute. If comments are Stack Exchange's second-class citizens, chat is its red-headed stepchild. It's not the same community, and it doesn't have the same vote/edit/close mechanisms to help moderate the "disease". Not that it matters, if people making id-requests never stick around as you suggest, not even to see their questions downvoted, closed and/or edited, then they're not going to stick around to see their questions closed now. They're never going to gain the reputation necessary to ask their question on chat instead.

Comment: You mention "the questions fit the Stack Exchange Q/A format" — I disagree with this statement. As I said before, they fit _a_ Q/A format, but if they fit _the Stack Exchange_ Q/A format, it's just barely. And I agree that your last sentence may end up being true: in fact, I might have said it myself, and added "and we don't lose much (if anything at all) from that."

Comment: @RossRidge *"the fact that we have a community of experts that are good at answering the questions"* with other kinds of questions yes but with id requests the number of users who can produce high quality answers diminish considerably and most answers end up being one liners which look nothing short from a random guess. while they might answer the question in the end the answer is still crap and ends up being deleted because of a high number of downvotes

Comment: @RossRidge *"if people making id-requests never stick around as you suggest, not even to see their questions downvoted, closed and/or edited, then they're not going to stick around to see their questions closed now. They're never going to gain the reputation necessary to ask their question on chat instead."* they can by asking/answering other kinds of questions. we're **Anime and Manga** not **Anime and Manga Identification Request**

Comment: @Memor-X They can but they won't.

Comment: @RossRidge which then brings us to what Krazer said in the question *"We're not here to be someone's personal search engine/concierge service, we're here to ask and answer questions about the world and culture of anime and manga."*. if a user comes here just to ask id request questions then they are just proving him right in thinking they are only using us as their personal search engine.

Comment: I disagree with the idea that identification requests only help the asker. When answered, they sometimes make suprisingly good (as in serendipitous) anime / sci-fi / whatever recommendations. But of course that is entirely subjective.

Comment: @Pwassonne some people have felt the same but the problem remains when the questions and answers just bad and are taking away too much time from the community to fix. personally while i would love to discover new Shoujo Ai/Yuri titles through ID Requests but i feel that it's a disservice for them when we have a horrible id request for a hentai about a shouta having sex with multiple lolis says it's yuri when nothing they describe even hints at it

Comment: I've never had the chance to answer an ID request (tried to once, but somehow my answer didn't send and by the time I realized, someone had answered. Turns out we had it right, too ^^) but if I did, I'd do my best to provide an objective description of what the media in question is like, or at least a description that completes what the identification request said. Like "what's this post apocalyptic anime where there's a robot that does this and that?" "it is ___, it's like your description because ___, and it's also rather graphic and has a deep message".

Answer (score -6):

Just my 2 Cents.

1 - This was a ridiculous small time frame. For a matter of this magnitude you should have allowed at least six months discussion

2 - ID requests are basically all I'm interested in answering on this site, since the rest of the questions seem of even lower quality, like questions about some boring stuff from Naruto, Bleach, One Piece or whatever kids watch these days.

Comment: If you aren't aware, the ongoing discussion on id-req questions has been is a [long standing one](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=identification), spanning nearly three years, so having to go through it for another 6 months seems unreasonable to me. If you feel that the varieties of question on the site are "questions about some boring stuff from Naruto, Bleach, One Piece or whatever kids watch these days," please feel to leave some feedback on meta, so we can make an attempt to keep your interest. We can't help you if you don't speak up and tell us.

Comment: in regards to point 1 we had this meta post on the FEATURED ON META section in the question lists and pinned on chat not to mention it was at the top of the meta question list almost the entire time so 2 weeks to me seem enough time for anyone who could [participate in the meta](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) post their opinion. it wasn't like we hid it so no one could post their opinion

Comment: Two weeks maybe enough for people that visit regularly. Which seems fairly unnecessary seeing how few questions get asked anyway. I liked, for example, this question http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/34223/ but it got closed for dubious reasons.

Comment: Just my two cents as well: comments like "like questions about some boring stuff from Naruto, Bleach, One Piece or whatever kids watch these days" doesn't seem to........how do I put it? What exactly makes a high quality question? Anyway, I totally agree that there needs to be some way of making sure questions are not the "Zomg, there was a pink haired girl who was she?" variety. Maybe there could be a monthly pizza/caffeine prize for "highest number of grammatical/sentence structure edits?"