# Can the tooltip that shows up when asking [identification-request] questions be updated to reflect we're on the process of deprecating them?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-warnings

As @Memor-X has mentioned [in the other meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2816/1530), we need to adjust the wording of the tooltip on asking a question tagged as id-request.

Can we get it to be changed to:

> The Identification Request tag is deprecated and now off-topic, see [our discussion](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/what-wed-like-to-do-about-those-gosh-darn-identification-requests-questions?lq=1) on the topic. Existing questions are currently in the process of removal.

The "How to tag" sidebar also mentions identification requests — that line should be removed.

(Just reposting the request here so it is tagged as a feature-request)

Comment: "depreciated" should be "deprecated", and "existing" is better than "current".

Comment: t y @Gao-senpai