# Identification Request Cleanup: Phase 2 - Blacklisting

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, identification-questions

[Continuing](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2812/63) with our our cleanup of "identification request", as detailed in [this proposal](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2806/63).

Phase 2: Blacklisting (ongoing until *June 6, 2016*, note the length was shortened after receiving feedback from users)

- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Ask the CMs for assistance in closing all remaining "identification-requests" (that have not been closed), <s>apply a [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) on **ALL** questions tagged with [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) (and tag synonyms, as needed)</s> (this has been moved to Phase 3) , and blacklist the tag. The tag will stay on the post, but it will not be editable by all users, except for moderators and CMs.

  - When a tag is blacklisted, any and all post that have said tag will not be accepted. While editing is allowed on locked questions by the moderators, subsequent edits to post with the blacklisted tag will remove the tag from the question.
  - For those with the delete privilege, please start voting to deleting incoming posts that are identification question but are not tagged as such. For those who cannot vote to delete, please flag these post.

Phase 3: Deletion (starting *June 6, 2016*, note the length was shortened after receiving feedback from users)

- Ask the CMs for assistance to delete all "identification-requests" without a question score of 4 or higher AND at least answer with score of 3 or higher.
- Ask the CMs to apply a [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) on **ALL** questions tagged with [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) (and tag synonyms, as needed). *Moved from Phase 2.*

As always please let us know if you have questions or comment on the details or procedures made in this post.

Comment: That blacklisting effort couldn't come any sooner.  There are quite a few more identification requests just popping out of the ether.

Answer (score 6):

I tested the blacklisting in the mobile site and got this warning.

[image]

It looks like the HTML isn't displaying properly; it seems that the code is being interpreted incorrectly as text to be displayed. This issue does not appear in the full site.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to any more general issues with mobile web, since I only just started using it. I can try to check later.

Comment: Can you create a separate bug report for this issue? Especially if it turns out to not be related to this particular incident.

Comment: @JNat: FWIW I tried doing something similar on Math.SE (where "homework" was blacklisted) and did not experience any issues. I'll write a separate post though.

Comment: [Here's](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/2829/2604) the new post.

Comment: Cool, thanks @Maroon!