# HTML in customised blacklisted tag warning does not display properly

Tags: bug, tag-warnings

As I wrote [in another meta post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2827/2604), the warning that appears on the mobile website, when the now-blacklisted [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) tag is used, does not display properly. The HTML for the link to the meta post about our new policy is interpreted as the text to display. This was not a problem when I went on the mobile site for Math.SE and tried using the blacklisted [homework](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag; the link to the relevant meta post was displayed properly.

[image] [image: screenshot from Math.SE]

I also tried Judaism.SE (where [torah](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah) cannot be used), and the links in the custom warning looked fine, but those were to other tags that the user might want to use, rather than site posts.

Comment: Looks like the difference here was that the Math site was grabbing markdown, and this one HTML. We've fixed this box on Anime so that it uses Markdown too, so it should be displayed properly now. I won't mark this as completed though, 'cause the actual underlying bug (the sites not using the same route) is not fixed.

Comment: @JNat: thanks. I take it that this was also a problem on the full site then?