# Swift deletion for new id requests under different tags

Tags: discussion

Now that the id request tag is blacklisted, people are coming in and posting new id requests with tags like [manga-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-production) and [anime-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-history) and the tags for shows they think resemble the show they're looking for.

As part of [Phase 2 of the id request cleanup](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2824/7579):

> For those with the delete privilege, please start voting to deleting incoming posts that are identification question but are not tagged as such. For those who cannot vote to delete, please flag these post.

So far, we've done a good job closing these questions, but a less good job deleting them. It's best if we don't have them around so new users don't get the idea that they're still allowed.

Those with [at least 4,000 reputation](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) can vote to delete questions immediately after they're closed, as long as the score is -3 or lower. Those with [at least 2,000 reputation](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) can vote to delete questions that have been closed for two or more days. Everyone can flag.

So, if you see a new id request with some other tag, please:

- Downvote and vote to close.
- 4k+ users, vote to delete any closed id request at -3 or lower.
- 2k+ users, vote to delete closed id requests older than two days. You can find closed questions by entering `closed:yes` in the search box, and then arrange them from newest to oldest and scroll down until you're at two days ago.
- Everyone else, flag as "in need of moderator intervention" and mention that the question is an id request.

Don't worry about anything that's actually tagged [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request); those will be either deleted or historically locked in Phase 3. It's just new questions trying to sneak in with some other tag that we have to take care of.