# Please blacklist the "identification-request" tag and lock all question with the aforementioned tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, allowed-topics, identification-questions

**Request:** I would like to request the CMs blacklist the "identification-request" tag, close the remaining open questions tagged with it and apply an historical lock on all questions tagged with this tag.

**Reasoning:** As vetted by this [meta discussion](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/what-wed-like-to-do-about-those-gosh-darn-identification-requests-questions), we've decided to start deprecating and removing identification question from our site. As part of Phase 2, we would like to blacklist the tag to prevent it from being used in the future. <s>We would like to lock all current identification question as a further reminder to users that, while theses question were acceptable in the past, they are no longer welcome on our site.</s> (Moved to Phase 3.)

---

**The Background**: Breaking these changes into three phases is intended to gradually ease all users into what can be considered a very drastic change to the landscape of our community. The "identification-request" tag used to be our most popular tag, but due to a long history of low quality and neglected questions (and answers), support (and favor) for the tag has waned drastically.

- Phase 1 was intended as a reminder to users that we're going to stop support the tag and to please stop asking these questions. Closing new identification requests was indented to deter and starting reducing the number of identification question coming in.
- Phase 2 is intended to be a direct roadblock indicating to new users that they can no longer use the tag. Locking the question, as indicated prior, is intended to warn users stumbling into an old identification question that these questions are no longer on topic and that they should stop asking.
- Phase 3 is intented to be cleanup. While we have a lot of identification questions, many of them are of low quality, abandoned, or otherwise unanswerable. While we are getting rid of these questions, we'd still like to leave a few examples of good identification question, as a legacy of sorts. There will be a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) for this at a later time.

Comment: This is intended to really put the process in the fast lane, right?  I'd have thought that the other Meta post made our intents *very clear*.

Comment: Yes. Each step is intended to up the ante as most user to frequent or know about meta, we need to be explicit with them on matters such as this. This feature request is more of a formality to keep in line with prior precedence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tag has been blacklisted, and 1295 questions closed. None should remain open, and they'll all appear as having been closed by me.