# Identification Request Cleanup: Phase 3 (Final) -- Delete & Lock

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, identification-questions

### Phase 3: Delete and Lock

[Continuing](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2824/identification-request-cleanup-phase-2-blacklisting) with our our cleanup of "identification request", as detailed in [this proposal](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2806/63).

I would ask the CMs to do the following as the *final* part of our three-phase process to remove identification questions from our community.

- Please delete all "identification-requests" without a question score of 4 or higher AND at least an answer with a score of 3 or higher.
- Please apply a [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) on **ALL** questions tagged with [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) (and tag synonyms, as needed).

  - If it's not any extra work, please give a brief synopsis of the number of questions that were deleted and the number that will remain locked.

As always, please let us know if you have questions or comments on the details or procedures made in this post.

[image: See][image: Ya]

Farewell [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request).

[image: A Final Adieu]

Answer (score 7):

This has been completed. [1637 were deleted](http://pastebin.com/wP74uCDZ), and [396 locked](http://pastebin.com/rTq91vN8). [As with closing before](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2826/49), the questions will appear as deleted or locked by me.

Comment: [This question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/31607/2604) was closed as an ID request, but since it wasn't tagged as such, it seems to have been overlooked.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I did the cleanup _for the tag_, so questions that have been mistagged since the tag was blacklisted were not caught in this. Those should be deleted _by the community_ as they come in, much like they're being closed.

Answer (score 1):

For verification and archival purpose, I have compiled [the list of questions to be deleted with post ID, title and score](https://gist.github.com/nhahtdh/108f8a930f219f05799bd84d86c43661), based on the conditions above.

The list above is generated from [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/497973), which will stop working next week, when Data Explorer is refreshed with a new dump.

```
select p.id as [Post Link], p.title, p.answercount, p.score, q.score
from posts p left join (
  select a.parentid, max(a.score) as score
  from posts a
  where a.posttypeid = 2
  group by a.parentid
) q on p.id = q.parentid
where p.tags like '%<identification-request>%'
and (p.score < 4 or q.score < 3 or q.score is null)
```

After fixing a derp in my query, the number of questions to be removed (1638) now more or less matches the number from JNat's post (1637), with the exception of one post which has been removed earlier by Oded. The one exception aside, **I have confirmed that both delete lists contain the same questions**.

[The number of remaining questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/497978) (396) matches [the number currently on the site](https://anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=[identification-request]+is%3Aq), so there seems to be no hiccup in the process. For extra precaution, **I have compared and confirmed that the list of questions from Data Explorer matches the list from JNat's post**.

Note that the remaining questions cannot be accessed via [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) when they are locked. Hopefully, the tag is still recorded in the question, so that [the search query](https://anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=[identification-request]+is%3Aq) still works.

Comment: Looking at some posts I had made under the tag, the tag seems to be still preserved in the locked questions themselves.