# Does Vocaloid count to our Music Identification Exception?

Tags: discussion, identification-questions, acceptable-questions

After Identification Requests were removed we [kept Music Identifications](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3868/1587) under the prevision that the asker knew the series it came from.

[A recent question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/47779/what-is-the-name-of-the-song-playing-in-the-background) (while an answer to this Meta wouldn't make it any more on-topic regardless of the answer) asked about a Hatsune Miku song. it got me thinking that do knowing that a song is a Vocaloid song count towards our Music Identification Exceptions? do we need any more previsions in regards to Vocaloid Song Identifications beyond knowing it's a Vocaloid song? eg.

- Knowing which Vocaloid sang it (Hatsune Miku isn't the only Vocaloid, there's Rin and Ren, Luca, Kaito, Meiko)
- Having a link to the song
- etc.

Comment: FWIW, if I didn't miscount, searching for ["vocaloid"](https://anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=vocaloid) returned 3 other music ID questions related to Vocaloid: https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/26978, https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21927, https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/35660

Comment: @AkiTanaka yes but i think the first 2 were before we did the ban and the other is just a general bad music id request where they just use whatever tags as a quick peak at the video shows no vocaloids

Comment: No prob, just want to mention those questions for the sake of completeness of this discussion.

Answer (score 4):

We have to be careful with these types of questions as they to dip quite a bit into the realm of user-created content such as doujinshi and user created music videos.

A Vocaloid characters are typically used with the music composing community for things related and unrelated to anime and manga, amongst them are some notable works such as Bad Apple!!, Just Be Friends, the World is Mine, Black Rock Shooter, Melt, and Rolling Girl, to name just a few. Many of these songs have had remasters, remixes, resamples, or even live/real voice covers. Just because an Vocaloid is identified, it doesn't mean there's a definitive version. There can be different versions of the same song by different Vocaloids form the same of different composers.

While we don't want to discourage question on fan made content, we should limit the scope of these questions to we're not looking for a needle in a haystack. Not all fan made content are created equal. We can't always know what someone else is thinking out and we can't expect them to give us the clues we need to find them. Therefore I propose the following.

Unless we definitively know which Vocaloid performs and at least the composer, and/or artist behind the work (like we as for a series, episode and approximate time for series-based music id-requests), music identification questions do not comply will be marked off-topic.

The ones that give at least include them must give at one of those artifact (image or clip linking the work with it's creator) that connect it to the work they are looking for. Such questions will be tagged with the [vocaloid](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocaloid) as the "series" and [music](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) as the accompanying tag.

Questions not related to music identification, but pertain to Vocaloids, whether that is music or art created using/of them and related fandom will still be considered separate and on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

My opinion would be that Vocaloid related music ID requests *can* be on topic, if they can be tied to, or related to anime. A sample of such is the question Aki linked [Origins and information about the song "Kokoronashi"](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/26978), where the OP assumes it might be related or part of an anime based upon the images and some research.

I do however think that just *knowing* that it is a Vocaloid song, should not make it on topic. All though the avatars are often animated, and might even sometimes follow anime like styles. Vocaloid as is, is but a piece of software, allowing just about anyone to make a synthesized song, based on what they type.