# Is there a way to find old post?

Tags: discussion

I joined this community back years ago and asked about finding an old (80's) anime. The answer I got was accurate but the Anime Stack-Exchange community was curated since then and old posts aren't visible anymore. I would like to know if there are archives where I can search for that answer. Back then I was without means of buying a copy of that anime, but these days I want to do so. If there is no way to get my old posts, then I would ask again the `identification-question`, right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identification requests have since been deemed off-topic — see [this Meta post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2805/49) if you wanna dig into the reasoning, etc.

As a part of the clean-up process, most of these questions were indeed deleted.

I can still see 'em, though, and you should too... provided you *know* where they are. [Here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/22628/49) and [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/13128/49) are the two deleted questions associated with your profile — hopefully one of those is what you're looking for.