# The Help Center needs a few minor touch ups

Tags: discussion

The help center article "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" could use a couple of minor improvements:

> ### Help! There's currently no tag for the series I want to ask about and I don't have enough reputation to make one... What can I do?
>
> If you find that the tag for the particular series you want to ask about does not exist, simply tag your question with the "[retag](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag)" tag and another user with the [appropriate privilege](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag) will retag your question accordingly.

Both links go to the page on the main site for questions with the tag [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag). But, I think it is intended that the second link should go to the [create tags](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) privilege page in the help center. So, could the second link be updated to go to the corresponding privilege page?

> ### Are you looking to ask a question about to identifying a particular anime or manga related media?
>
> Please note that **ALL anime and manga identification questions** are [off-topic](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2725/policy-review-image-only-id-requests/2726#2726) and will be [put on hold](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) regardless of how much context is provided.

The "on-hold" label is no longer used after the [release of the new post notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700). The linked help center article "[What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)" also does not use the term "on-hold" anywhere. So, can the words "put on hold" be replaced with "closed" in the text quoted above?

Answer (score 3):

*This is a work-in-progress proposal in revising the [help/on-topic](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page. Feel free to discuss/raise an idea in the comment section below, or post a new answer if the change is major.*

---

**Change proposal:**

- Redirect "retag" to the "Ask a Question" page with 'retag' tag prefilled: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=retag
- Redirect "appropriate privilege" to the "Privileges - Create new tags" help page: https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags
- Change "put on hold" to "closed"
- Redirect identification-related links to the newer policy: [What we'd like to do about those gosh darn "identification requests" questions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/what-wed-like-to-do-about-those-gosh-darn-identification-requests-questions)

Comment: I would like to see consistent use of highlighting in the section titled "What about other questions regarding anime and manga?". Currently, the first bullet point uses italics for emphasis, as well as for the example sentence, as well as the suggestion for where to take such questions. The other bullet points use bold for emphasis, italics for the example sentences, and also for suggestions (mostly). Some links to Meta discussions are displayed in full, whereas others are behind some text: again, a consistent format of "See: <link to Meta post>" would be nice. Sorry for being pedantic! (:

Comment: I like the idea of having the text "retag" link to the Ask a Question page with that tag prefilled. We should definitely link to the newer policy on ID requests, too.